# search in pdf files with javascript in hta

Tags: javascript, search, pdf

I have a folder with many PDF files inside, I need a code that is able to search inside those PDF files with javascript.

I read in many places that this is not possible to do it.
It's hard to me to believe that it isn't possible, because if windows explorer is able to search text within those PDFs, I think it is also possible with my HTA.

I thought about two different ways that it may be possible:

1. Some windows ActiveX that allows searching.
2. External script / batch call from the HTA.

What do you think?

Thanks,
Rotem

Comment: @Pekka do you have any idea about my question?

Comment: no, it might be possible using some Windows scripting but I don't know how

Comment: Ok, I found this: findstr /m "1234567" *.* >> res.txt if I'm using it in a batch file it is searching for the string but it is searching in the PDFs.. any idea?